# Error when using npm install

Tags: npm, installation

when I try using npm to install a package, it always throws a 405 method not allowed error.
Here is a sample:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Comment: are you using a proxy?Are you using Nexus or Artifactory?

Comment: Adding the proxy statement to the npm install resolved the issue.  I was originally using the incorrect proxy.  We have several so i had to find the correct one.  Thanks for the assist